# My NTFS partition no longer automounts

Tags: fstab, automount

Linux used to automount my windows. But it was a 32-bit Windows, so after installing 64-bit Windows, it no longer automounts. It keeps showing at the start - `The disk drive for /windows is not ready yet or not present. Continue to wait, or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.`
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you had an entry in fstab for your old Windows and you reinstalled it got a new UUID.
You need to update fstab with new UUID.

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Change current old UUID for your Windows to the new one.

suggested settings if you do not have these:
defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,windows_names

Also do not hibernate Windows as then it will not mount.

Comment: thank you ! that message is not coming any more. But before it used to show '430 GB Filesystem' under devices. Now thats not there. is that normal?

Comment: i used that first command and saw in the list that it was mounted.
THANKS FOR THE HELP!!!!

Comment: Since it was not mounted before it defaulted to your 430GB entry. Better to label all partitions with gparted when created or Disks afterwards with labels that make a little more sense. If you used Nautilus to review the 430GB that would also mount it. And it should show all partitions anyway.